# Javascript to wait the end of a function including asynchronous MYSQL Queries from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having Javascript problem to wait a function done before the below line is called. The previous function is including the [Javascript MYSQL](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) Queries calls (one of the library of node.js). Then it will be looks like:

```
function first() {
    /**
    * a lot processes to execute
    * including Asynchronous processes
    * like running Queries using Javascript MYSQL Library from node.js
    */
    console.log("I am the first one!");
}

first();
console.log("I am the second one!");
```

Then when i execute this, it happening like:

```
I am second one!
I am first one!
```

How do i make them run by keeping the queue order?

***NOTE:*** Now for everyone who confusing the question, please jump/follow my newly created question again: 
Everyone please follow/jump into this new question: [Node.js MYSQL to detect the INSERT/UPDATE completeness of a Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951916/node-js-mysql-to-detect-the-insert-update-completeness-of-a-query)

Comment: [No, it doesn't happen like that.](http://jsfiddle.net/FxSZS/)

Comment: Unless there's an asynchronous action in that first method.

Comment: Does your `first one` line reside in an asynchronous callback? Because what you're saying cannot happen otherwise.

Comment: You'd only see the second message before the first if the first were in a callback handling some asynchronous thingie's completion.

Comment: The code you have given is misleading, it's impossible for this to happen with that code

Comment: @Michael: Asynchronizing the log method wouldn't change the order in which it got called, and any self-respecting logger would log messages in the order they were sent.  Stuff ends up async before that.

Comment: Guys, sorry for my poor info. Now please check again the /* Comment */ block.

Comment: It doesn't matter, if you log like that inside the `first` function, it will be logged before the `"second"`. The control doesn't return to the line `console.log("I am the second one")` until the `first` function has been executed, which (according to the OP code) includes logging the `"im the first one"`

Comment: @Esailija NO IT DOESN'T if you are running the MYSQL queries. They are going Asynchronously.

Comment: @4lvin: YES IT DOES, *regardless.  That's how JavaScript works*.  The only way "second" appears before "first" is if "first" is in a callback.  As written, this code will *always* log "first", then "second".

Comment: @4lvin ok [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FxSZS/5/) we have about a dozen of async calls inside the `first`, they are irrelevant in this regard. If I were to put the log call inside a callback of one of those calls, then it would happen of course. But that's not what the code in the OP is doing.

Comment: @Esailija You are not running any of Javascript MYSQL queries inside, which are separately running / asynchronously.

Comment: I give you that they are not MYSQL queries, but they do run asynchronously in the same sense.

Comment: @4lvin: MySQL is not special.  JS isn't going to be like "oh, this code is talking to a MySQL server!  I'm going to violate all my rules about how stuff runs, because MySQL is too cool for rules!".  No, it runs *exactly the same* as any other asynchronous code.

Comment: Everyone please follow/jump into this new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951916/node-js-mysql-to-detect-the-insert-update-completeness-of-a-query

Answer (score 1):

Pass a callback to the 2nd function to the call to the 1st function.  At the end of the 1st function, invoke theh callback:

```
function one(parm, callback) {
    // do something
    callback();
}
function two() {
    // do something else
}

one("my parm", two);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to structure your code to use a call back

```
function first (callback) {

// do your stuff

callback.call();
}

first(function () { console.log("I am the second"; });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is very common on people who had programmed in other languages before `JavaScript`, such as `c/java`, you think `JavaScript` will do the following:

```
 Line of code1. Execute,when it's done go to the next.
 Line of code2. Execute,when it's done go to the next.
 Line of code3. Execute,when it's done go to the next.
```

What actually happens in JavaScript is more like:

```
 Line of code1. Execute
 Line of code2. Execute
 Line of code3. Execute
```

For `JavaScript` to work as you expect you need to program it in a event oriented way, that means, you need to specify which functions you want run in what specific order. To do so in `JavaScript` you need to make use of `callbacks`, for example:

```
 function1 (parameter A,function2){
        //...   
        function2(parameter B,function3)} 

 function2 (parameter B,function3){//...} 

 function3 (){//...}
```

You could generalize more the example above, however i think leaving it like this makes it easier for understanding. You can find many articles on the web about this. The first result of a `google` search gave me this [link](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/).

Happy coding!